# iTunes Connect submit App

Tags: ios, xcode6, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, itunes-app

I get the next error in iTunes Connect while I try to submit my app, that doesn't use any entitlements, the error is:

Apps that use the entitlements [com.apple.developer.in-app-payments] must have a privacy policy URL for [English, Spanish]. If your app doesn’t use these entitlements, remove them from your app and upload a new binary.

Please help me sort this out, as I don't know what should I change in my binary.

Answer (score 5):

It seems you've activated the "In-app purchases" capability for your project. If you don't have in-app purchases in your app, click on your project in Xcode, and then on the "Capabilities" tab, and toggle off "In-App Purchase":

[image]

**EDIT:** If you do have in-app purchases, you can fix the error by going into your app in iTunes Connect, and adding the URL to your privacy policy:

[image]

Comment: They were always off and show everyone the equal error

Comment: Do you have an `.entitlements` file? With Quick Open (CMD+SHIFT+O) search for "entitlements", and see if you have IAPs added there. Though, this file (if it exists) should be the same as the "Capabilities" tab

Comment: No such file in my project , so I do not understand the error that gives me to send the review

Comment: It might just be an iTunes Connect bug :( What if you try putting a dummy URL in the privacy policy field?

Comment: That solution is not possible, as it has to be a valid rise.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when I had Apple and Stripe implemented in my app.  AndI was tr I did NOT have in-app purchases turned on.

The fix was to put a unique URL for the marketing site in the Wizard where you Add Build To Test.  Don't put something like http://www.yahoo.com

Answer (score 0):

Disable InApp Purchases from your AppId from developer Account and in Xcode Go to Project -> Target -> Capabilities and off InAppPurchases